# Does UPI support Deep Linking on Apple IOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking, webintents, upi

With deep linking using "intent" one can initiate payment from your app and complete payments in UPI enabled apps like Tez, BHIM, PhonePe. This is enabled due to Android Intent APIs. I do not find anything similar on IOS. Also I did not find any mention of Deep linking support for IOS in NPCI specification documents.

Comment: hey, were you able to figure a way out? i tried opening the URL with UIApplication.shared.open but nothing happens. I have tez and bhim installed on the device.

Comment: Hi, Did you get the solution? I'm also looking for the same. I'm using Ionic.

Comment: Any way around here guys, I am also facing same issue.